# C++ Bubble Sort (Ascending) function not returning results

Tags: c++, function, sorting

I'm trying to use a bubble sort in a function instead of inline, and I seem to be having an issue with it returning results. As in currently, it's giving me no results at all. Here is my code that I have written up so far...

Basically, the user tells the program how many numbers they want to enter (up to 20 allowed) then it inputs those into an array in the order entered. Then it prints the values entered, sorts, and prints the sorted values. Or at least that's what is supposed to happen.

Thanks for the help in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int vault[20] = {};         // array to store the 20 values
int val = 0;                // variable to pass values to the array
int amt = 0;                // variable to get the amount of numbers the user is going to enter
int i = 0;                  // loop counter


// Bubble Sort Function Prototype
void bubble (int (&vault)[20], int val);

// Bubble Sort Function
void bubble (int (&vault)[20], int val)
{
int swap = 1;       // flag used to indicate swaps occuring
int temp = 0;       // holder variable
int x = 0;          // loop counter
int y = 0;          // second loop counter

for (x = 0; (x < val) && (swap = 1); x++)
{
    swap = 0;

    for (y = x+1; y < val; y++)
    {
        if (vault[x] > vault[y])
        {
            temp = vault[x];
            vault[x] = vault[y];
            vault[y] = temp;
            swap = 1;
        }
    }
}
return;
 }



 int main()
 {
cout << "Welcome to the Bubble Sort exe\n\n" << endl;
cout << "Please enter in the amount of numbers you would like to enter: ";
cin >> amt;

cout << "Please enter the values you wish to enter: ";
for(i = 0; i < amt; i++)
{
    cin >> vault[i];
}

cout << "The values you entered in order are: ";
for (i = 0; i < amt; i++)
{
    cout << vault[i] << ' ';
}

cout << "\n\nLet me just sort that for you!" << endl;

bubble(vault, val);

cout << "\n\nHere are the values in ascending order:\n" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < val; i++)
{
    cout << vault[i] << ' ';
}


system("pause");

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Altough it isn't a really a bubble-sort algorithm your problem is that you store the size of the array to be sorted in amt and you pass val to the sorting function, which is initialized with 0. Furthermore you check if i < val, which is the same problem. Your functions works if you add val = amt; after cin >> amt; ...

Comment: This did it...of course its something as small as that that trips me up on this. Thank you for the help! Also, everybody keeps saying this isn't really a bubble sort, but I'm seeing this exact form all over forums and from documents straight from my professor, I guess I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathias pointed me in the correct direction. I had forgotten to initialize the variable 'val'. When I corrected that, it works perfectly.

As for everybody saying that this is not a classic bubble sort, I have seen this exact form on multiple sites and on slides from my prof., what is wrong with this way of writing it?

I'm trying this now instead, and it's completely failing on me (*sigh*):

```
void bubble (int (&vault)[20], int val)
 {
    bool swap = true;       // flag used to indicate swaps occuring
    int temp = 0;           // holder variable
    int x = 0;              // loop counter
    int y = 0;              // second loop counter

    while (swap = true)
        {
        swap = false;
        x++;
        for (y = 0; y < val - x; y++)
        {
            if (vault[y] > vault[y+1])
            {
                 temp = vault[y];
                 vault[y] = vault[y+1];
                 vault[y+1] = temp;
                 swap = true;
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you've written *isn't* a classic bubble-sort algorithm.  Bubble-sort iterates through the entire array each time, swapping elements with their immediate successor, doing this over-and-over until no more swaps occur.

In the traditional implementation, there are no "nested for-loops."  There's one for-loop nested in a while or repeat-until structure.

The algorithm is called "bubble" because the lowest value "bubbles up" to the top ... with roughly the speed of a bubble trapped in very viscous oil.

(Compare with, say, the Shell sort, which is a slight-seeming alteration to Bubble that makes a tremendous difference.  And to the quintessential and definitive Quicksort.)